# PHP preg_match_all how to match multiple line loop

Tags: php, regex

I want to pick the text from mysql query result from like below

```
    $text = <<<TEXT
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         id: 1
   installs: 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
         id: 2
   installs: 2
*************************** 3. row ***************************
         id: 3
   installs: 3
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


TEXT;
    preg_match_all("#(?:\*{5,}[^\r\n]+\*{5,})((?:\\1|\d+ rows in set )*)#", $text, $match);
    print_r($match);
```

result is wrong,I want to get is:

```
[1]=>
         id: 1
   installs: 1

[2]=>
         id: 2
   installs: 2

[3]=>
         id: 3
   installs: 3
```

How is the correct expression to pick all correct .

Answer (score 0):

You should only try to match in your regex what you actually want to extract.
In your case, it's only id and installs.

The regex in this case should be something like:

```
preg_match_all("/id: ([0-9]+)\n\s+installs: ([0-9]+)/", $text, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

You'll have as a result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id: 1
   installs: 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => id: 2
   installs: 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => id: 3
   installs: 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

It's quite similar to what you expect, you'll get an array of all the row found, and each row is an array where the first element is the whole regex match, the second element is the id and the last one is the installs.

Answer (score 0):

You could first match the line with the multiple asterix chars, followed by 2 capturing groups.

```
^\*{5,}\h+\d+\.\h+row\h+\*{5,}\R\h+(id:\h+\d+)\R\h+(installs:\h+\d+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\*{5,}\h+\d+\.\h+row\h+\*{5,}`
- `\R\h+` Match a newline and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(id:\h+\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match `id:`, 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 1+ digits
- `\R\h+` Match a newline and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(installs:\h+\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match `installs:`, 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1vEV3S/1)

Then you can remove the full match from the array and keep only the capturing groups.

```
$re = '/^\*{5,}\h+\d+\.\h+row\h+\*{5,}\R\h+(id:\h+\d+)\R\h+(installs:\h+\d+)/m';
$text = <<<TEXT
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         id: 1
   installs: 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
         id: 2
   installs: 2
*************************** 3. row ***************************
         id: 3
   installs: 3
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


TEXT;

preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach($matches as &$match) {
    unset($match[0]);
}
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => id: 1
            [2] => installs: 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => id: 2
            [2] => installs: 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => id: 3
            [2] => installs: 3
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/KIsmq)

Answer (score 0):

You can use next preg_match condition:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/id: \d+\n.*installs: \d/im", 
    $text, 
    $match
);
```

Here you can try it: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9779796a40a248ec357a03b8d436c011&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)